# Replace everything within the parenthesis in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**We have a user filed in our SQL server database that is stored as LastName, FirstName and an associated address as shown below. 
   LastName, Firstname (Address)
I would like to select the above user field without the address. What would be the best way to accomplish a format as
    LastName, Firsname. 
**

Comment: That would depend on what's inside the brackets.  Perhaps you could show some samples.

Comment: So you want to remove all within parenthesis including the parenthesis  itself?

Comment: Yes just remove the parenthesis completely and create a new column to store the results and i do have some null values

Answer (score 1):

You have only two options for this type of problem

If you have only single `(` and `)`, in your entity value then you can deal with using  with CHARINDEX, PATINDEX and REPLACE.

If you have more then you will have to use CLR code to support regexp

[Reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic

```
Declare @str varchar(65) = 'amol kshirsagar(thane)'
select LEFT(@str,CHARINDEX('(',@str) - 1),Right(@str,len(@str) - CHARINDEX('(',@str) + 1)
```